# Что означает запись в коде Nisza ** nisza

Tags: c++, ооп

строка 15  Что означает запись в коде Nisza ** nisza ?

```
 #include <string>
 #include "ustawienia.h"

 class Nisza;
 class Mieszkaniec;
 class Sasiedztwo;

 class Srodowisko{

 public:
 const unsigned int wiersze, kolumny;
 const unsigned long liczbaNisz;

 private:
 Nisza ** nisza;

 public:
Srodowisko(unsigned int _wiersze,
 unsigned int _kolumny);

 ~Srodowisko();

 void lokuj(Mieszkaniec * mieszkaniec,
 unsigned int wiersz, unsigned int kolumna);


 Sasiedztwo ustalSasiedztwo(unsigned int wiersz,
 unsigned int kolumna) const;

 unsigned long liczba(RodzajMieszkanca rodzaj) const;

 bool martwy();

 void wykonajSkok(unsigned int wiersz,
 unsigned int kolumna);

 void wykonajAkcje(unsigned int wiersz,
 unsigned int kolumna);

 void wykonajKrokSymulacji();

std::string doTekstu() const;
 };
```

Comment: объявление поля `nisza` с типом `Nisza **`

Comment: что nisza  может указать на указатель, указывающий на объект типа  Nisza, и что возможно нужно вспомнить о правиле трех(пяти).